# Wordpress method to require account creation/login after user views X number of pages?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, woocommerce

I'm trying to find a method for allowing anonymous visitors to view a set number of pages after which the website requires an account to be created or the user to login (at which point they have free reign).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely foolproof but you can accomplish this using cookies. Could play with it a little to suit your needs. But essentially this would be a way to check for logged in users, and utilize cookies to see potential pageviews in more than a single session. Of course cookies can be deleted, so there's always that but ultimately your pageview limit still applies.

You would put this in above any HTML tags in your header, on all pages *except for the sign up/login page* to avoid redirect loop.

```
<?php

  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    
    // First check if the user is logged in. If so we do nothing.
    die();

  } else {
    
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['cookie_name'])) {
      
      // If no cookie is present set it with a pageview value of 1. We assume this is a first time visitor.
      setcookie('cookie_name', 1, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 30 Day cookie adjust as needed.

    } else {
      
      // If the cookie is present, check to see that the visitor hasn't reached the threshold.
      if($COOKIE['cookie_name'] < 4) { // Put your pageview total to check against
        
      $new_cookie_value = $COOKIE['cookie_name'] + 1; // Add a pageview to the total in the cookie value
      setcookie('cookie_name', $new_cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // Re-set the cookie
      
      } else {
         // redirect to sign up/login page if over the pageview threshold
      }
    }
  }
```